# Modify ellipse coordinates in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have been trying to move an ellipse in pygame.

This is my code:

```
import pygame

import pygame

pygame.init()
oW = 400
oH = 500

black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
gameDisplay.fill(black)


Sun = pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, red, (400,400), 60)


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        
        #Key input over here
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                oW = oW + 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                oH = oH + 10
        Orbit = pygame.draw.ellipse(gameDisplay, blue, (200, 250, oW, oH), 1)
    pygame.display.update()
```

How could I make it so that rather than the ellipse constantly duplicating itself and making copies, it's coordinates would just move the original(first one)? Currently, if you run the program below, the ellipse will make copies of itself in the new coordinates rather than modifying the original so there will be a lot of ellipses if you press a or d. After researching online, some people were suggesting putting a black shape over everything and then redrawing it but that's not really what I'm going for here, I just want the shape to update without constantly duplicating itself.

Comment: The duplicates results from not deleting the old one. So clear screen / redraw screen / or delete the ellipse before redrawing it. You must clear and redraw, like painters algorithm. For no flickering use a backbuffer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you aren't drawing a background. When you draw a new circle the next frame, the old circle isn't overwritten. Simply add `gameDisplay.fill(black)` to the start of your loop. You can of course change the color if you like.

Comment: this is mentioned in my comment above. So this is really answer? I have marked your answer as helpfull, because it is my answer too ;-)